# Selenium for getting data of google reviews

Tags: selenium-webdriver, django-rest-framework, webdriver

Failed to start browser /snap/firefox/current/firefox.launcher: no such file or directory

```
 options = Options()
 driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
```

when i add this

```
options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/firefox"
```

`but it should not be added it should automatically get the firefox binary location`

`These are my versions selenium==4.11.2 ,webdriver-manager==4.0.0, firefox==116.0.3`